# remove patterned prefix from list in gnu make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I have a list of files:

```
files := xx_foo1.c yy_foo2.c zz_bar1.c aa_bb_bar2.c
```

Is there any way of removing everything up to the last underscore from the list to get `foo1.c foo2.c bar1.c bar2.c`?

I was looking into using `patsubst`, but I would need two`%`'s -- one for the first part to be ignored, and one for the last part to be kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done but it's a little gross.  You want something like this:

```
final := $(foreach F,$(files),$(word $(words $(subst _, ,$F)),$(subst _, ,$F)))
```

This says, for each element in `files` we convert the `_` to a space, now we can use our per-word functions to manipulate it: extract the last word in the list of words.

*ETA*
ReAl points out below that this can be simplified using `lastword`:

```
final := $(foreach F,$(files),$(lastword $(subst _, ,$F)))
```

Comment: a _little_ gross??     I feel sorry for the guys who have to maintain it. :)  It does what I need though.  Thanks.

Comment: or even `final := $(foreach F,$(files),$(lastword $(subst _, ,$F)))`

Comment: Oh yeah... hah!!  Forgot about lastword :p :)

Answer (score 2):

As I see it you are using the underscore as separating character between hierarchical names. GNUmake is well equipped to work with such a scheme if the character is `/`: file name functions.

So your example should simply boil down to

```
$(notdir $(subst _,/,$(files))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the external program — `sed` — and enjoy all its power

```
files := xx_foo1.c yy_foo2.c zz_bar1.c aa_bb_bar2.c
f := `echo $(files) | sed -e "s/[[:alnum:]]*_//g"`

all:
    echo $(f)
```

Comment: Nah. Always prefer _make_ mechanisms over the shell.